# Todo List JS / appendChild only works on click, I don't want that

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am practising JS on a To Do list, and I want to append a close icon to my LI tags with JS.
But it only appends the icon when I click the LI tags.. I want the icon to be there already.
The appendChild syntax isn't in a click function..

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
// Select all LI and add class on click
   document.querySelectorAll(".thing").forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener("click", () => {
   item.classList.toggle("checked");
   });
 });

// Create close icon and append it to LI elements
const myList = document.querySelectorAll(".thing");
let i;
for (i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  const txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myList[i].appendChild(span);
};
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/Papasaurus/pen/RwRrdLr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add position:relative to class 'thing'

```
li.thing {
    position: relative;
}
```